# How to convert String of array to Integer array

Tags: r

I have a string as `"2_5_6"`. i need to get the numbers in the string **As numeric**.

Here is what i tried:

```
indices = apply(strsplit("2_5_6","_" ),2 ,FUN = as.numeric)
```

But, it complains with:

```
Error in apply(strsplit("2_5_6", "_"), 2, FUN = as.numeric) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I don't know what should be my Margin parameter ?

What is the simplest solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `scan` to convert to numeric while splitting at `_`

```
scan(text = "2_5_6", what = numeric(), sep="_", quiet = TRUE)
#[1] 2 5 6
```

Or if we are using `strsplit`, the output is a `list` of length 1. It can be either `unlist`ed or extracted (`[[`)

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit("2_5_6", "_")))
```

`apply` expects the input to have some dimensions and here it doesn't have

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use a Comma Separated Files ( `.csv` ) file.

Use this file to set and get params useful to configure your algorithm/procedure.

Save the file with `.csv` extension and read it using the function `read.csv(...)`.

In your case, use:

```
myMargin <- read.csv(file="mymargin.csv", header=FALSE, sep="_")
```

If you need more information, this is the documentation:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
as.numeric(strsplit("2_5_6","_" )[[1]])
```